# text file download issue in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

VS 2013, MVC application need to download files from the particular drive. i have written the below code. All the files are displayed in the grid. below hard coded the path but still not able to download the file

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult downloadlogfiles(string logfilename)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\Logs\try.txt");
        string fileName = "myfile.ext";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Is the path "d:\Logs\try.txt"" accessible by application? If yes try check if the file exists and then download

Comment: yeah its able to access the file and even it converts  text file into bytes

Comment: How are you calling this method from client side...?

Comment: through Java script ... i am displaying the list of document in the JQ grid on the click of the cell i will call the method using the Jquery post menthod

Comment: ' $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Jobs/downloadlogfiles",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { logfilename: filename }
        });'